# Why doesn't overloaded function bind to more specific overload?

Tags: c++

Consider the following overloaded functions:

```
template <class T>
void foo(const T& v)
{
    std::cout << "Generic version" << std::endl;
}

void foo(std::pair<const void*, std::size_t> p)
{
    std::cout << "Pair version" << std::endl;
}
```

Below, I expect the second overload (the one that takes an `std::pair`) to be called:

```
int main()
{
    const void* buf = 0;
    std::size_t sz = 0;
    foo(std::make_pair(buf, sz));
}
```

However, this code in fact calls the generic version.  Why doesn't it bind to the overload that specifically takes an `std::pair`?  Is this a compiler bug? I'm using a pretty old compiler, GCC 4.1.2

Comment: "However, this code in fact calls the generic version." [Not on clang++3.4](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f63c920491593bdb) Compiler? Version?

Comment: Please note the compiler+version you're using (and mine, Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) , reports "Pair version".

Comment: Not on g++ 4.5.2 either.

Comment: Okay so I guess it's a compiler bug

Comment: g++ 4.7.2 result: Pair version

Answer (score 3):

- You need to declare your specialized function as a template
- Your specialized argument type must follow the template parameter (i.e. be a const reference) as well.

Try

```
template <>
void foo(const std::pair<const void*, std::size_t>& p)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: IIRC, explicit specializations of function templates need to have the same parameter and return types (as the primary template). Also, overloading typically has less problems than specializing.

Comment: But why should that be necessary?  Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: Updated with more explanations